# My Bootstrap Alert box does not close when dismiss button is clicked

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, reactjs, alert

I am trying to add a dismissable bootstrap alert box to my React element. I believe I have everything in proper order, but when I click the X, it will not close.

```
<div id="index-alert" className="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
  <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"></button>
  {this.getIntlMessage('contactsInfoAlert')}
</div>
```

Is this a React specific problem? Or am I not using the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue using Bootstrap 4 and it was resolved by adding the following line to **index.js**

`import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';`

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget a 'X' between the `button` tags?
Also `alert-dismissable` should be `alert-dismissible` but this is not really important.

Your code work as show here: http://www.bootply.com/xQItB8Wv0B

So it's probably an issue with React... Have you tried using [react-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap) instead?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem few days back, thing being i forgot to add util.js in my bootstrap project which holds the necessary javascript files required for alert-dismissible to work
add all the required bootstrap javascript components and try again.